# How can I SET field_name to GROUP_CONCAT on rows with matching id's in same table?

Tags: mysql, merge, group-concat

I have a table with two columns, '`sale_id`' and `'product_name'`.  There are duplicate `'sale_id'` values in cases where one sale included more than one product.  I want to concat the product names so that for sales that included more than one product, the product names are included in the same field value.  I tried to set this as a group_concat to another table and also tried to create a new table, but I get errors.
I tried variations of :

```
UPDATE table1 SET `product_name` = GROUP_CONCAT(product_name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM products_table
WHERE table1.sale_id=product.sale_id;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only sincere recommendation to make is to change your table structure so that it is [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This will get you your solution in two steps:

1. Change your table structure to model sales, products, and the relation between sales and products as 3 tables.
2. Add a 'view' which creates the structure you want to select. This is optional, as you could just have the application layer build this query as needed. Use of views this way could be as simple as personal preference, or could be a significant part of your organization's approach to databases.

The tables will look like this:

**Products**

- id
- name
- etc.

**Sales**

- id
- begin_data
- end_data
- etc.

**Sales_Products**

- sale_id
- product_id
- etc.

I suppose you can imagine how to fill these with data. The view will then take a query like this:

```
SELECT Sales.id, GROUP_CONCAT(Products.name) 
FROM Sales_Products 
JOIN Sales ON sale_id = Sales.id 
JOIN Products ON product_id = Products.id 
GROUP BY Sales.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with scenarios and instruction comments.

SQL:

```
drop table if exists products_table, new_products_table;

-- This section is just prepration for data for this demo. No need to do it for your own existing table and data.
CREATE TABLE products_table(sale_id int, product_name varchar(200));
INSERT INTO products_table VALUES(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c');

-- You need to do the following steps
-- Make a clone of the table
CREATE TABLE clone_products_table LIKE products_table;
INSERT INTO clone_products_table SELECT * FROM products_table;
SELECT * FROM clone_products_table;

-- Update original table products_table with assistent of the temp table
UPDATE products_table p2 
    SET p2.product_name = (
        SELECT group_concat(p1.product_name) FROM clone_products_table p1 WHERE p1.sale_id = p2.sale_id
        );
SELECT * FROM products_table;

-- Clean the temp table
DROP TABLE clone_products_table;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM clone_products_table;
+---------+--------------+
| sale_id | product_name |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 | a            |
|       1 | b            |
|       2 | c            |
+---------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- Update original table products_table with assistent of the temp table
mysql> UPDATE products_table p2
    ->     SET p2.product_name = (
    ->         SELECT group_concat(p1.product_name) FROM clone_products_table p1 WHERE p1.sale_id = p2.sale_id
    ->         );
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM products_table;
+---------+--------------+
| sale_id | product_name |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 | a,b          |
|       1 | a,b          |
|       2 | c            |
+---------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- Clean the temp table
mysql> DROP TABLE clone_products_table;
```

Comment: What is the problem? a,b,c are just sample values. You will get your data in ur environment. @pbnyc

Comment: I don't understand your code.  I'm not going to manually input id #s.  Please explain in a way that makes sense.

Comment: @pbnyc I update the post by adding some comment. Please check again.